# 2d Array Text file C# Login not working

Tags: c#, authentication

I am currently having trouble with a piece of code I have been writing lately. The aim of the code is to read a text file with user details, check their login information and then allow them to login. However I am having trouble and when I execute the code. Only the last row in the text file is "working". The program can register that there is more tahn one username, however it always thinks the password is incorrect. I dont know how to better explain this. If you have any questions please ask and thanks for helping.

This is my code

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string UserList;
            string UsernameString;
            UserList = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\dagostinom18\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assignment\Assignment\users.txt");

        int iLength = UserList.Length;
        string[,] users = new string[iLength, iLength];

        foreach (var row in UserList.Split('\n'))
        {
            int y = 0;
            foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(','))
            {
                int x = 0;
                users[x, y] = col.Trim();
                if (users[x, y] == Username.Text)
                {
                    UsernameCheck = true;
                    UsernameString = Username.Text;
                    RowNumber = x;
                }
                y++;
            }
        }

        if (UsernameCheck == false)
        {
            LoginError.Text = "No such username";
        }
        else
        {
            if (Password.Text == users[RowNumber, 1])
            {
                Main f3 = new Assignment.Main(); 
                Form1 f4 = new Assignment.Form1();
                f3.Show(); 
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome ");


            }
            else
            {
                LoginError.Text = "Incorect Password";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what my text file looks like

```
matt, 12345
admin, 67890
test, abcde
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger. You'll see what's happening. Hint: your loop should probably stop when it finds a match..

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how your code should look in more clean state.

```
string password = PasswordTxt.Text//you should use your control names
string userName = UserNameTxt.Text//your control

bool validUsers = false;

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("@"C:\Users\dagostinom18\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assignment\Assignment\users.txt""))
{
   string textUserName = line.Split(',')[0].Trim();
   string textPassword = line.Split(',')[1].Trim();

   validUsers = textUserName == userName && textPasword == password;

}

if(!validUsers)
{
    //show error, user credentials are not valid
    return;
}

//go log in.
```